# Errors: Module 'pygame' has no 'init' member, and others

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pygame

I am following the Python Crash course, some of you may have saw my last posts, I have decided to redo the whole alien invasion project so I would understand the code and the purpose of the code better.

I am using VScode, and I have installed the base Python extension, and I also have the Python (PyDev) extension.

[If you click here](https://www.programmer-books.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Python%20Crash%20Course%20-%20A%20Hands-On,%20Project-Based%20Introduction%20to%20Programming.pdf), you can see the book I am following, but I am sure the syntax mentioned in the book is correct.

I am on page 241 of the book. Here is the code:

```
import sys
import pygame

def run_game():
    # Initialize the game and create a screen object
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 800))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:

        # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        # Make the most recently drawn screen visible.
        pygame.display.flip()

run_game()
```

The code seems to run fine on the terminal but it says I have 3 problems with the code.

The first one is: Module 'pygame' has no 'init' member

Second one: Module 'pygame' has no 'QUIT' member

And the third: Unused variable 'screen'

I know that the third problem is more of a warning so disregard it (I am still showing it because it might have something to do with the problem)

The terminal feedback is fine as you can see:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\holca\Desktop\alien_invasion 2> & C:/Users/holca/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/holca/Desktop/alien_invasion 2/alien_invasion2.py"
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
PS C:\Users\holca\Desktop\alien_invasion 2>
```

Why does the IDE say that these are errors?

Thank you for taking the time to read this, looking forward to the responses. I am fairly active so if you need more info I can reply.

Comment: The errors are clearly incorrect as those are valid methods of pygame, as evidenced by the fact that the code runs without issues. That also means that your installation seems fine, but clearly the IDE is confused.  Perhaps there is something wrong with the IDE setup? It is curious though that it complained about these, but was okay with `pygame.display.set_mode()` and `pygame.event.get()`. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the IDE extensions or maybe reinstalling the IDE completely?

Comment: ok I will try that thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

It's something about "pylint", not your code. The third one: Unused variable 'screen', it
is because you created the variable 'screen' but have not used it. The first one and the second one, you can solve it through configuration:

```
Open settings.json file add these settings:
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--disable=all",
    "--enable=F,E,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode",
    "--unsafe-load-any-extension=y", //or add this one: --extension-pkg-whitelist=pygame
  ],
```

These settings are the default settings of pylint, you can refer to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_default-pylint-rules) page:

```
"--disable=all",
"--enable=F,E,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode",
```

if you only add

```
"--unsafe-load-any-extension=y"
```

or

```
"--extension-pkg-whitelist=pygame"
```

you will get "Missing module docstring" and "Missing function or method docstring" warning.

---

Explains:

Why did you get the first and second waring? This is because "pylint" can't lint a C extension module. You can refer to [this](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/technical_reference/c_extensions.html) page for more information. The "init()" function is in the file of "base.cp38-win32.pyd", under the pygame package, and "pylint" can't lint it. The "QUIT" is the same problem, it is in the "constants.cp38-win32.pyd" file.
[A C extension for CPython is a shared library (e.g. a .so file on Linux, .pyd on Windows)](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html?highlight=pyd)

Comment: Thank you for explaining I will work on it and get back to you

Comment: I did it a bit differently since I essentially just switched the linter to Flake8 instead of PyLint, your response still helped me though since you said PyLint cannot lint it. Also thank you for putting in the time and effort.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to suggest you switch the linter. Pylint is not a good linter, with a lot of problems. I am just too focus on the solution of the problem which pylint caused.